# Get different values from different elements in loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops

Ive got 10 html elements. I need value attributes from 8 and classes from 2 elements and put them all to one array. Id is the key.

How to solve this with JS or jQuery?

I started with `.each()` but I discovered quicky that I can't use exceptions in that loop - it makes the changes for all the elements.

```
var myArray = {};

$( '.need-values, .need-classes' ).each( function () {

    myArray[this.id] = $( this ).val();
});
```

I know that I could use 2 `.each()` loops and combine values to one array but the thing is that some are checkboxes - I need to use `if` statement in loop.

Comment: Checkboxes should have different selector so that you can play around with conditions for those elements..

Comment: inside `each` you can use `if ($(this).is(".need-values") { ... }`.

Comment: Yes, these 2 elements are checkboxes _but_ if I use `if` statement in `each()`, it makes changes to both / all elements that are selected.. Am I doing something wrong then?

Comment: You can use multiple selectors to match all the elements you wish to extract data from https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/ and use if statement in the loop to determine which attribute (class or value) you want to add to myArray.

Comment: can you please give an example on fiddle or snippet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside your loop, do this

```
myArray[this.id] = $(this).is('need-values') ? $(this).val() : $(this).attr('class');
```

if the element has the `need-values` class, it will get the value, else, it will get the classes. Of course, you can suit this to your own needs with different cases and whatnot

```js
var myArray = {};

$('.need-values, .need-classes').each(function() {
  myArray[this.id] = $(this).hasClass('need-values') ? $(this).val() : $(this).attr('class');
});

console.log(myArray);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="a" type="checkbox" class="need-values" value="a">
<input id="b" type="checkbox" class="need-values" value="b">
<input id="c" type="checkbox" class="need-values" value="c">
<input id="d" type="checkbox" class="need-classes d" value="d">
<input id="e" type="checkbox" class="need-classes e" value="e">
<input id="f" type="checkbox" class="need-classes f" value="f">
```

Comment: I have one extra question about your answer: what if I need to make `if` check inside this `if` check? E.g If this has class `need-values` - get value , else if this is checked, use 1, else use 0.

Comment: That's fine, you could just use an `if, else if, else` instead of the ternary `? :`

Answer (score 0):

Query provides .map() for this:

```
var items = $('#main p').map(function () { return $(this).text(); }).get();
```

.map() iterates over its elements, invoking a function on each of them and recording the return value of the function in a new array, which it returns.
You can find the documentation [here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/).

Or you could solve it your way with .each():

```
var items = [];

    $('#main p').each(function (i, e) {
      items.push($(e).text());
    });
```

Or another way whitch is if you want more options is Multiple Selectors. As you can find a documentation about that [here](https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/).

This is if you want elements in one array. For example like this:

Instead of this:

```
<div id="main">
<p>Text1</p>
<p>Text2</p>
<p>Text3</p>
</div>
```

Have this:

```
["text1","text2","text3"]
```

Answer (score 0):

at first give all 10 elements a common `class` (e.g `common-class`).

then you can do like this.....

```
var array=[];
$(".common-class").each(function(){
      if(this.tagName=="DIV"){
         array.push($(this).attr("value"));
      }
      if(this.tagName=="INPUT" && $(this).attr("type")=="checkbox"){
        array.push($(this).attr("class"));
      }
      ..................and so one
})
```